# sigaddset vs pthread_sigmask

Tags: linux, signals

What is difference between `sigaddset()` vs `pthread_sigadd()` functions?. In the following code, the signal is coming if the `pthread_sigmask()` function call is uncommented.

```
    sigemptyset(&signal_set);
    if( sigaddset(&signal_set,SIGUSR1) == -1){
            printf"sigaddset() retuned error number %d\n",errno);
    }
    //pthread_sigmask ( SIG_BLOCK, &signal_set, NULL );
    while(1){
            if(sigwait(&signal_set, &sig_number) == 0){
                    printf("Got signal\n");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Added code tags and change first letter capital

Answer (score 0):

`sigaddset()` and `pthread_sigadd()` are used together but do different things.

- `sigaddset()`:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigsetops.3.html:

> These functions allow the **manipulation of POSIX signal sets**.
>   `sigaddset()` and `sigdelset()` add and delete respectively signal from set.

- `pthread_sigadd()`:

After you have a signal set, you can mask it via `sigprocmask()`/`pthread_sigmask()`.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html,
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html:

> `sigprocmask()` [as well as `pthread_sigmask()`] is used to fetch and/or change the signal mask of the
>          calling thread.  The *signal mask* is the set of signals whose delivery
>          is currently blocked for the caller (see also `signal(7)` for more
>          details).

Regarding the code you posted, experiencing a signal coming through is how it's expected to work.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigwait.html:

> The signals defined by `set` **shall have been blocked at the time of the call** to `sigwait()`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So you must always block the signals first and then wait for them.